# 時間を望んだformatで表示させる方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

pandasによるデータフレームで0~23のhour列と、0~60のminute列があり、その2列からtime列("%H:%M"の形式)を作りたいと考えています。
ですが、hour、minuteともにint型だからかエラーが出てうまくいきません。
どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 15], [2, 30], [3, 0]], columns=['hour', 'minute'])
      : df
Out[2]:
   hour  minute
0     1      15
1     2      30
2     3       0
```

上記のようなデータフレームが与えられたとして、 dataframe 自身のの文字列操作だけでやるとすると、

```
In [3]: df[['hour', 'minute']].astype(str).apply(lambda s: s.str.zfill(2)).apply(
      :     lambda s: s.str.cat(sep=':'),
      :     axis=1
      : )
Out[3]:
0    01:15
1    02:30
2    03:00
dtype: object
```

になるかなと思いました。

Answer (score 1):

> hour、minuteともにint型だからかエラーが出てうまくいきません。

だったら文字列型に変換するとよいのでは

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'hour':[1,2,3], 'minute':[10,20,30]})

r = df.hour.astype(str) + ":" + df.minute.astype(str)
#0    1:10
#1    2:20
#2    3:30
#dtype: object
```

apply 使うとこんな感じ

```
r = df[['hour','minute']].astype(str).apply(':'.join ,axis=1)
#0    1:10
#1    2:20
#2    3:30
#dtype: object
```

２つ目の方法であれば文字列型でなくともできる

```
r = df.apply(lambda d:f"{d.hour}:{d.minute:02d}", axis=1)
#0    1:10
#1    2:20
#2    3:30
#dtype: object
```

これが一番シンプルかな